# Crash when calling interrupt() on a boost::thread, which has another boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, crash, interrupt

I'm getting a crash when calling `interrupt()` on an outer `boost::thread`, which runs an inner `boost::thread`, which is connected to a `thread_guard`. It's not crashing when calling `join()` manually on the inner thread.

Crash:
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::thread_interrupted'`

Source:
https://gist.github.com/elsamuko/6e178c37fa2cf8742cb6bf512f2ff866

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread_guard.hpp>

#define LOG( A ) std::cout << A << std::endl;

void double_interrupt() {
    boost::thread outer([] {
        boost::thread inner([]{
            while(true) {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
            }
        });

        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
            LOG("Interrupting inner");

            boost::thread_guard<boost::join_if_joinable> guard(inner);   // crashes
            // inner.join(); // works
        }
    });

    LOG("Interrupting outer");
    outer.interrupt();
    outer.join();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    LOG("Start");

    double_interrupt();

    LOG("End");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile & Run:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46c512bf9a385fff

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04. with g++ 7.5.0 and got the latest boost 1.78.0.

I opened this issue on github, too: https://github.com/boostorg/thread/issues/366

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number OP does, in the section "Compile & Run"

Comment: Does your example ever work in a version of boost?

Comment: I tried with 1.67.0 and 1.78.0 and both crash.

Comment: @LoiusGo code should be in the question not on external sites

Comment: I don't see you calling anywhere `inner.interrupt`; But I don't know `boost:thread` library very well, so not sure how these interrupts work exactly. With standard library `std::thread` your code will hang forever because of infinite loop, or crash (if no infinite loop) because of no join.

Comment: @pptaszni An infinite loop would be a progress, because it's not crashing then :)
But you can replace the `std::sleep` with a `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()`, it crashes, too.
I think, the outer `interrupt()` influences the inner thread somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution. The problem was, that the `join()` of the `thread_guard` waits for the inner thread with a `condition_variable::wait()`. `condition_variable::wait()` itself checks, if it's interruptible and throws an exception.

The solution is to use a custom `thread_guard` with `disable_interruption`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread_guard.hpp>

#define LOG( A ) std::cout << A << std::endl;

void work() {
    size_t sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1E7; ++i) { sum += 1; }

    LOG("work: " << sum);
}

// helper struct to interrupt a boost::thread within a boost::thread
struct non_interruptable_interrupt_and_join_if_joinable {
    template <class Thread>
    void operator()(Thread& t) {
        if(t.joinable()) {
            boost::this_thread::disable_interruption di;
            t.interrupt();
            t.join();
        }
    }
};

void double_interrupt() {
    boost::thread outer([] {
        boost::thread inner([] {
            while(true) {
                boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
                work();
            }
        });
        {
            boost::thread_guard<non_interruptable_interrupt_and_join_if_joinable> guard(inner);
            LOG("Interrupting inner");
        }
    });
    LOG("Interrupting outer");
    outer.interrupt();
    outer.join();
}

int main() {
    LOG("Start");
    double_interrupt();
    LOG("End");
}
```

Run here:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a365e40a2bd574cc

Comment: That coincides with [my analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71482828/crash-when-calling-interrupt-on-a-boostthread-which-has-another-boostthre/71486609?noredirect=1#comment126374697_71486609) earlier. However, I do feel it looks like a library bug, since the exception emanates from `join_noexcept` and breaks the abstraction.

Comment: I opened a [PR](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/pull/367), let's see what the maintainers say about this :)

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing `std::thread` and `boost::thread`.

Only Boost Thread knows about interruption points. Use that to fix:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/813c04aeb1f5ddf7)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread_guard.hpp>

void double_interrupt() {
    boost::thread outer([] {
        boost::thread inner([] {
            while (true) {
                boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1));
            }
        });
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1));
            std::cout << "Interrupting inner" << std::endl;
            boost::thread_guard<boost::join_if_joinable> guard(inner);
        }
    });
    std::cout << "Interrupting outer" << std::endl;
    outer.interrupt();
    outer.join();
}
int main() {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    double_interrupt();
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
Start
Interrupting outer
End
```

Comment: The `std::sleep` is only for simulating work. `boost::sleep` [interrupts](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption), which I don't want here. Remove the `std::sleep`, then it crashes, too.

Comment: Of course, because then you have no interruption points again. You need interruption points, because thread interruption is _cooperative_. So, e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d43d7d3bdd122447 (or somewhat more verbose/elaborate: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baa6bf98615be3e1

Comment: This is still crashing when some work is done in the inner thread: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e9a2fa8673a0beb

Comment: I think it's a race. You setup the `thread_guard` *after* it was started. Even flipping that makes it fail some of the time, but less so when compiled with threadsan/ubsan (so, slower). That smells like a timing-related race. Then again, using helgrind/drd told me the exception is raised inside `join_noexcept` ([stacktrace](https://i.imgur.com/2BNUqLE.png)) which would suggest a library bug.  Perhaps they missed a `disable_interruptions` instance somewhere?

Comment: For reference the test program I am debugging that with (removed the console output to avoid the unwanted data race diagnostics) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8a91127da27c5c3

Comment: I found a solution below, it's a missing `disable_interruption`, because `join()` is interruptable.